# How to get a list of online users in Authlogic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, authlogic

I've added a last_request_at field to my user table in Ruby on Rails, so now I can call the authlogic method User.logged_in.count and it returns the correct value. But how do I get a list of all logged in users? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`User.logged_in.all` ?

Comment: Thanks! Still learning Ruby on Rails, didn't know I could do that.