# Display realtime list of logged in users ( Maybe using AuthLogic)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic

I need to display a real-time or at least near real-time list of users currently logged into my site.

I'm using the AuthLogic gem to manage Registration/Login & Session management.
Is there a quick way for me to find a list of current usernames logged into the site using authlogic?

I ask this new question because there seems to be conflicting answers on whether this is possible:

[Rails and Authlogic. Show currently logged in users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039697/rails-and-authlogic-show-currently-logged-in-users)

[How to get a list of online users in Authlogic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3083129/how-to-get-a-list-of-online-users-in-authlogic)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just tried it out there and the following code allows you access to all logged in users and their model attributes.

```
def online_users
  return Member.logged_in
end

@loggedIn = online_users
@loggedIn.each do |member|
  print member.username
  print member.email
end
```

You must add the 'last_request_at' authlogic column to your user table.

Answer (score 0):

We can list the list of online users with my rails application by use of active record session store, please see this github app https://github.com/mohanraj-ramanujam/online-users